# Chrome extension inline installation not working if no www

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a problem with my Chrome extension inline installation.

It works at `www.feedart.co`, but it's not working when I load `feedart.co`.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: To what did you set the website(s) when configuring inline installation for this add-on?

Comment: Then perhaps you should change that to `feedart.co`. Or if changing it does not make it work with both, then you can add both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Chrome Webstore [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#verified-site):

> For security reasons, inline installations can only be initiated by a page on a site that is verified (via Webmaster Tools) as being associated with that item in the Chrome Web Store. Note that if you verify ownership for a domain (for example, `http://example.com`) you can initiate inline installation from any subdomain or page (for example, `http://app.example.com` or `http://example.com/page.html`).

Therefore, you should verify the top domain (`feedart.co`) and set that as the associated website for the Webstore item. It would then work on both that domain and the `www.` subdomain.